# Angular: got undefined value when assign new variable with $rootScope variable

Tags: angularjs, int, angularjs-ng-repeat, rootscope

As mentioned on title, I have small issue to assign new variable with `$rootScope` variable.

I have variable `$rootScope.adulttotTicket` with value 2. the value is `int`. So what I want is just to assign new variable `newVal` to `$rootScope.adulttotTicket` variable.

```
<p data-ng-init="newVal = $rootScope.adulttotTicket"></p>
```

but when I output variable `newVal`, it show nothing on my browser. So I try to edit at plunker, so I found out the value `newVal` is undefined. I don't have any idea what to do here.

`newVal` should easily have value 2 from `$rootScope.adulttotTicket`. but I got nothing. see on this plunkr  [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uw3Uj1HmcK2eJYCUlYWj?p=preview)

Hope get idea from anyone. thanks !

Comment: Just wanted to mention that what you are trying to do sounds like a bad idea - as we all know, [gobal state is evil](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) and ng-inits are too. Not saying there are no cases where its needed, but it should generally be a sign to rethink your design.

Comment: You should use `controllers` rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: It shows `adulttotTicket: 2
newVal: unassigned` I guess thats what you need right?

Comment: We had this strange bug and the only thing work is convert a variable to object. like $rootScope.ticket.adulttotTicket

Answer (score 1):

Access `$rootScope` in view by using `$root` instead:

```
<p data-ng-init="newVal = $root.adulttotTicket"></p>
```

I updated your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/A8yCg64ZFee7aOU0e5oX?p=preview) and it does work fine.

Comment: still unassigned..  supposedly `newVal` show value 2

Comment: @FaiZalDong I updated the plunker. It does work now but you should not do it like this ...

Comment: But my question is to assign new variable to `$rootScope.adulttotTicket`, eg: `<p data-ng-init="newVal = $rootScope.adulttotTicket"></p>`.  what you showing is you use back the value of `$root`

Comment: see this plunkr [https://plnkr.co/edit/21mGfltfkkHaOoLaGx3Q?p=preview].   supposed value `nv` get value `$root.newVal`

@lin

Answer (score 0):

When referring to `$rootScope` in a view use `$root` instead:

```
<p data-ng-init="newVal = $root.adulttotTicket"></p>
```

**UPDATE**

The reason why the above does not work is because you are not in a scope and so have no `$scope` to access the `$root` of! To fix you can declare your variable on the `$rootScope` in a run block as follows:

```
angular.module('myModule').
run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.adulttotTicket = 'unassigned';
});
```

You can then access this in the view (with no reference to `$root` or `$rootScope`) as follows:

```
<p data-ng-init="newVal = adulttotTicket"></p>
```

Comment: can guys show in plunkr? I have tried, but still not working... [https://plnkr.co/edit/uw3Uj1HmcK2eJYCUlYWj?p=preview]

Comment: actually I dont want to use controller, can you see my plunkr

Comment: @FaiZalDong I'm not using a controller.

Comment: [Updated your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UmaUNP0qDVUSrG3pr39i?p=preview), not a single controller in sight.